# How do I create multi indexed series based on columns and range of values and check if it sorted properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I created a series based on Letters: D, E, F and inserted values in this way from 0 to 9 on each row:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'letters': list('DDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFF'), 'numbers': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

  Output: 


  letters  numbers  
  0        D        0
  1        D        1
  2        D        2
  ....
  9        D        9
  10       E        0
  .....
  18       E        8
  19       E        9
  20       F        0
  ......
  28       F        8
  29       F        9
```

Then I created multi index on this Df with this code ( I wanted to check if this is correct way or there are other ways to create multi index)

```
  latestone = df.set_index(['letters', 'numbers'],drop=False)

output: 


                letters  numbers
 letters numbers                 
    D       0             D        0
            1             D        1
            ....
            9             D        9
    E       0             E        0
            1             E        1
            ...
            9             E        9
    F       0             F        0
            1             F        1
            ...
            9             F        9
```

Based on this or if there is any better way to create multi index , I would like to know if these values are being sorted lexicographically or not (True or False if possible).

Also, I would like to get the rows with index [2,5,7] for letter E.

Comment: Do you want a dataframe with the values the same as index? Seems unnecessary. Or are you just interested in creating the index?

Comment: @busybear I tried to do that but I was getting different outcome like this                                   [(D, 0), (D, 1), (D, 2), (D, 3), (D, 4), (D, 5), (D, 6), (D, 7), (D, 8), (D, 9), (E, 0), (E, 1), (E, 2), (E, 3), (E, 4), (E, 5), (E, 6), (E, 7), (E, 8), (E, 9), (F, 0), (F, 1), (F, 2), (F, 3), (F, 4), (F, 5), (F, 6), (F, 7), (F, 8), (F, 9)] I am not sure if this outcome will help me to get the solution which I want.

Comment: That does look like the index you want. The first element in each tuple is the first level of the index and the second element of the tuple is the second level of the index. I provided an answer which does this efficiently though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you would like to know is whether the values are sorted. No the values are not sorted. They appear exactly as arranged.

To be able to get the rows `[2,5,7]`you can use:

```
df.loc[[('E',2),('E',5),('E',7)]]
                letters  numbers
letters numbers                 
E       2             E        2
        5             E        5
        7             E        7
```

or

```
In [578]: df.loc[('E',[2,5,7])]
Out[578]: 
                letters  numbers
letters numbers                 
E       2             E        2
        5             E        5
        7             E        7
```

Comment: Alternative is `df.loc[('E', [2, 5, 7]), :]`

Answer (score 1):

To create just the index object, `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` will be easier in your case. Then you can use that index to create a dataframe with whatever values you need.

```
data = ...
mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('DEF'), range(10)])
pd.DataFrame(data, index=mindex)
```

This will not change order, but it is in the order you defined it. Use `sort_index` method to sort based on index. You can specify which level should be sorted first.